# Custom Widget <source_model> ChooserModel run local, but not online

Tags: adminhtml, ce-1.8.1.0, widgets

I have written a custom widget. It's run on my local installation (1.8.1), but not in my remote installation (same system).

If i select my widget from the select box i get a fatal error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/.../.../app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Options.php
>   on line 171

That is my ChooserModel, located in ***app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/ChooserCategories.php***:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_ChooserCategories {

    public function toOptionArray() {

        $arrOption;
        $arrOptions;
        $objCategories;

        if (Mage::registry('[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_ChooserCategories_value')) {

            $arrOptions = Mage::registry('[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_ChooserCategories_value');

        } else {

            $objCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

            $arrOptions = array();
            $arrOption = array();

            $arrOption['label'] = '(no filter)';
            $arrOption['value'] = 'none';

            array_push($arrOptions, $arrOption);

            foreach ($objCategories as $objCategory) {

                $objCategory->load();

                $arrOption = array();
                $arrOption['label'] = str_repeat("---", $objCategory->getLevel()) . ' ' . $objCategory->getName();
                $arrOption['value'] = $objCategory->getId();

                array_push($arrOptions, $arrOption);

            }

            Mage::register('[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_ChooserCategories_value', $arrOptions);

        }

        return $arrOptions;

    }

}
```

On line 171 in ***app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Options.php*** try magento to load the source_model by name. It's look like magento have the model not loaded. If i return the model-name i get the correct one:

> [Module]/choosercategories

Take a look into the config.xml for the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Helper</class>
            </[module]>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Block</class>
            </[module]>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
            </[module]>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Can anybody find the bug, or does someone have a tip for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

name your file `Choosercategories.php` instead of `ChooserCategories.php` (make `c` in categories lowercase) and the class name should change accordingly.

`Namespace]_[Module]_Model_ChooserCategories` becomes `Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Choosercategories`